# my add-on executing JS on http only not with https

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, add-on

I have an add-on package for Firefox.  It executes javascripts on certain websites, but it executes Javascript only for HTTP; I need it to be executed in HTTPS too.  Please help me.

This is my addon package: [Addon in Zip](http://myfbapps.info/youtube.zip).

Comment: Please consider using [Add-on Builder](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/builder), particularly the [page-mod package](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.3/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html). The GreaseMonkey script compiler is ancient and I doubt that anybody will be able to offer you much help with it.

Answer (score 1):

The first line in `wefwqfeqwef` in `youtube.js` is this:

```
if ('https:' == document.location.protocol) return false;
```

So, it looks like the code is specifically rejecting `https` URLs.